# print output is filtered but excel files unfiltered

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I wrote a code for json file and export it into excel with pandas module.
I added if filter in for-loop and print function displaying true in terms of this filter.
But in excel file, its not filtering output.
How can I modify it?
Thank you.

```
import json
import contextlib
import pandas as pd

class Game:
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_record):
        game = cls()
        game.league = json_record["ligler"]
        game.hometeam = None
        game.awayteam = None
        game.score = None
        if game_a := json_record:
            with contextlib.suppress(IndexError):
                game.hometeam = game_a.get("team1")
            with contextlib.suppress(IndexError):
                game.awayteam = game_a.get("team2")
        return game      
    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(
            str(item) for item in (
                self.league, self.hometeam, self.awayteam, self.score))

with open("example.json") as f:
    jsondata = json.load(f)

games = [Game.from_json(game) for game in jsondata["Value"]]

for game in games:
    if "Bundesliga" in game.league or "Arsenal" in game.hometeam:
        continue
    print(game)

df=pd.DataFrame(games)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
print("Saved.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the conditions into your list comprehension:

```py
games = [Game.from_json(game) for game in jsondata["Value"] if "Bundesliga" not in game.league and "Arsenal" not in game.hometeam]
```

The subsequent loop doesn't change the original list.

Comment: ah sorry, now i just click tick, thank you.